# Pillow - FileNotFoundError: No such file or directory: 'Lit_Bulb.jpg'

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter, python-imaging-library

[image]

I just downloaded and extracted `Pillow` through `PyPI`, and it seems the modules are now accessible, but when I try to test it adding an image, it shows this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python Projects\Button Puzzle (GUI).py", line 4, in <module>
    image = Image.open("Lit_Bulb.jpg")
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\PIL\Image.py", line 2288, in open
    fp = builtins.open(fp, "rb")
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'Lit_Bulb.jpg'
```

I put the jpg file in the PIL folder, hoping it would find it with the module, but I guess I didn't do it right, can anyone help?

The code I tried:

```
import tkinter
from PIL import Image, ImageTk

image = Image.open("Lit_Bulb.jpg")
photo = ImageTk.PhotoImage(image)
label = tkinter.Label(main_menu, image = phto)
label.image = photo
label.pack()

main_menu = tkinter.Tk()
main_menu.title("Button Puzzle")
main_menu.configure(background ="SlateGray3")
main_menu.geometry("200x100")

play_button = tkinter.Button(main_menu, text="PLAY")
rules_button = tkinter.Button(main_menu, text= "Rules")
play_button.pack()
rules_button.pack() 

main_menu.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 2):

Pass the *full path* to the file `image = Image.open("path_to_/Lit_Bulb.jpg")`, unless the file is in the same directory as your your `cwd` then python won't be able to find the file.

Comment: added paths. Could you tell me what is cwd? and where is the python cwd for that matter

Comment: cwd means current working directory. If you import os;print(os.getcwd) you will see your cwd

Answer (score 0):

1. It is always good practice to put your images or resources in the
   same folder as your directory of the main `.py` file. For example if
   you have your main files in c:\projects\myProject\ , then you should
   put the your images in the same folder `myProject`.

   This way when you open any file or image from within your code, all
   you need to do is write the name of the file or image. for eg. 
   `myImage = Image.open('Lit_Bulb.jpg')`.
2. If you don't put your images or files in the same folder than you can
   access them by specifying the exact directory when you open the file
   or image. For example, if my image is in a folder in `E:` drive, then I can
   access it using this.
   `myImage = Image.open('E:\myFolder\Lit_Bulb.jpg')`.

**Note-** if you have a big project where you need a lot of files and images, then you should put those images inside a new folder in the same directory as your `.py` files. After doing this, if you want to open those files, it would look something like this. `myImage  = Image.open('Images\Lit_Bulb.jpg')` since, the `Images`folder is in the same directory as the `py` file, you don't need to specify the whole directory.  Hope this helps.

Comment: myImage = Image.open('E:\myFolder\Lit_Bulb.jpg'). -esque search

Comment: and it worked! but I don't want to do this search for all my jpgs and such... even though I am just trying to make a small project puzzle I thought of, how can I make it so I can just type the name of the file instead of all the path?

Comment: Put the Image in the same same folder as your `.py` file. Your Image and `.py` file needs to be in the same directory. for example. if your `.py` file is in `E:\Myfolder\myfile.py` then your image should also be in the same folder like this. `E:\Myfolder\myImage.jpg` . Now you just need to write the name of image when you open it `myImage = Image.open('Lit_Bulb.jpg')`